# How to read a polynomial from a file?

Tags: c, linked-list

How to read polynomial from a file in c and save it as linked list.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
// make a structue
struct Projct1
{
  int Coefficient;//represent Coefficient of polynomial
  int exponent;//represent exponent of number
  struct Projct1 *next; // point the next structue
}Projct1;
void readFormFIle(Projct1 *x1);
void print(Projct1 *x1);
void Show(Projct1 *x1);
Projct1 *add(Projct1 *x1,Projct1 *x2);
Projct1 *subtrac(Projct1 *x1,Projct1 *x2);
Projct1 *multiply(Projct1 *x1,Projct1 *x2);

void main(){
  Projct1 *x1=NULL,*x2=NULL,*x3=NULL;
  int choice;
  do{
    printf("Menu\n\n");
    printf(" 1 - read from file\n");
    printf(" 2- show equation ");
    printf(" 3- add equation ");
    printf(" 4- subtrac equation ");
    printf(" 5-  mult equation ");
    printf(" 6-  show result");
    printf(" What command you need : ");
    scanf("%d", choice);

    switch (choice)
    {
      case 1:
        x1 = init();
        readFormFIle(x1);
      case 2:
        x2 = init();
        Show(x1);
      break;
      case 3:
        x3 = add(x1, x2);
      break;
      default:
        printf("wrong choice.Enter Again");
      break;
    }  
  }while(choice != 3);
}
```

Comment: 1. Define the format of the file to read. 2. Write some code to read the file and create a linked list.

Comment: Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings to catch coding problems like `int choice; ...  scanf("%d", choice);`.

Comment: And fix indentation, formatting your code properly.